# How can I efficiently update SwiftUI DatePicker to not allow future times, but always allow the current time?

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

I have a SwiftUI `View` that contains a `DatePicker` with `.datePickerStyle(.wheel)`. I want the user to be able to select dates and times in the past up to the current time, but no dates or times in the future.

There is a pretty straightforward way to get most of the way there:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Select Date and Time",
                       selection: $selectedDate,
                       in: ...Date(),
                       displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

However, after the next minute starts, the maximum becomes outdated: **the user can only select times based on the date and time when the `View` was created.**

For example, if the `View` that contains the `DatePicker` is presented at 12:44, once the time is 12:45, the user can still only pick times up to and including 12:44, but not 12:45.

To get around this problem, I created a ViewModel with a `@Published` `maxDate` that gets updated every minute, on the minute, and used that as the maximum value for the `DatePicker`:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var maxDate = Date()
    private var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        updateMaxDate()
    }

    func updateMaxDate() {
        timer?.invalidate()

        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentMinuteStart = calendar
            .date(bySettingHour: now.hour,
                  minute: now.minute,
                  second: 0,
                  of: now)!
        let nextMinuteStart = calendar
            .date(byAdding: .minute,
                  value: 1,
                  to: currentMinuteStart)!

        let remainingSeconds = calendar
            .dateComponents([.second],
                            from: now,
                            to: nextMinuteStart)

        if let seconds = remainingSeconds.second {
            maxDate = currentMinuteStart
            timer = Timer
                .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(seconds),
                                         repeats: false)
            { [weak self] _ in
                self?.timerFired()
            }
        }
    }

    private func timerFired() {
        print("timerFired()")
        updateMaxDate()
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Select Date and Time",
                       selection: $selectedDate,
                       in: ...viewModel.maxDate,
                       displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

extension Date {
    var hour: Int { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self) }
    var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self) }
}
```

This works, but there is an issue that I can't figure out: **I expect the `timerFired` function to be called just once every time it's a new minute, but instead it is called hundreds of times.**

The exact number of times `timerFired` is called varies, but it seems to usually around 700–1000 times, and causes a noticeable CPU spike.

I thought maybe it was somehow related to the View refreshing or multiple instances of the `ContentViewModel` object, however it is a `@StateObject`, so it should only be created once, and I was able to confirm it's only being initialized once by adding a `print` statement to its `init`.

How can I resolve this issue so the `maxDate` is only updated once? Or, is there a better way to set up a `DatePicker` to achieve this same behavior?

Comment: This looks way to complicated to me, why not create a timer that repeats and that fires once a minute (or perhaps twice per minute) and simply updates maxDate to the current time without all those calculations.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Then the DatePicker is not always up to date for up to a minute, or half a minute, respectively. Another solution I considered was updating it every second, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Or maybe skip all of this and have a checkbox next to the picker that says “Now” or something and that selects the current time whenever you use selectedDate.

Comment: IMO you are creating problem out of nothing (or more likely your QA does, lol). How much time is the majority of the users likely to spend on this screen, and how much time the whole workflow will take? for example if user would spend a few seconds, just allow current minute, and let the user to close and reopen this view if they really need the next minute. But if your workflow includes sending this time to the server, then even allowing next 2 minutes would make sense, since by the time the request is processed that time will be in the past...

Comment: Based on my user testing, some users tend to leave this screen with the DatePicker open across different sessions because they want to be able to come back to it quickly any time to enter a new item, so I want to prevent it from being outdated while also letting them leave it open if they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this by updating the ContentViewModel as follows:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var maxDate = Date()
    private var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        updateMaxDate()
    }

    private func updateMaxDate() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        // The number of seconds that have passed in the current minute
        guard let currentDateSecondsComponent: Int =
            Calendar.current
            .dateComponents([.second],
                            from: Date())
            .second
            else { return }

        // Figure out how many seconds it is until the next refresh
        let timeUntilNextRefresh: TimeInterval =
            Double(60 - currentDateSecondsComponent)

        timer = Timer
            .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeUntilNextRefresh,
                            repeats: false)
        { [weak self] _ in

            // Set the max DatePicker date to the current date
            self?.maxDate = Date()

            // Schedule the next update timer
            self?.updateMaxDate()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Upon further testing, when I was using the `DateComponent` way to determine the number of seconds until the next minute, it would end up scheduling a timer for a fraction of a second before the new minute, and since each timer fire would schedule another timer, it would fire many times until the new minute actually started.

I switched to subtracting from 60, which I know is not the `DateComponent` way, but it gets around this fraction-of-a-second issue and I can't foresee any major issues that would come from this.

---

**Update: I found a working solution that uses `DateComponent`**

After further experimentation, I found a solution that combines my working answer with the `DateComponent` approach while avoiding the issue where the function was called hundreds of times:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var maxDate = Date()
    private var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        setUpTimer()
    }

    private func setUpTimer() {
        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let nextMinuteStart = calendar
            .date(byAdding: .second,
                  value: 60 - calendar.component(.second,
                                                 from: now),
                  to: now)!

        let remainingSeconds = calendar
            .dateComponents([.second],
                            from: now,
                            to: nextMinuteStart)

        if let seconds = remainingSeconds.second {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = Timer
                .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(seconds),
                                repeats: false)
            { [weak self] _ in
                self?.maxDate = Date()
                self?.setUpTimer()
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```